# Composer autoload psr 4 wildcard expansions for matching all modules?

Tags: php, json, regex, composer-php, psr-4

I have this structure for my app,

```
myapp/
  config/ (config and setup)
  module/ (tons of modules!)
     Article/ (one of the modules)
        source/ (<----- note that all php psr4 classes are stored in this folder)
           Article
              Model/
                 ArticleModel.php
                 ArticlesModel.php
              Controller/
              View/
     Book/ (one of the modules)
       ....(the structure is the same as Article's)
  public/  (web site doc root)
  vendor/
    composer/
    ...(other packages)
```

And this is my composer.json,

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "0.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Foo\\": [
                "module/*/source/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "library/"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see that I have this `"module/*/source/"` in .json. Reason I do this is because I want to avoid writing every module out as it is going to be **a long list**. And it is not flexible too when I have new modules then I have to make changes to the  .json.

But `"module/*/source/"` is not working. So can I do regex or something in this .json so that it is 'intelligent' enough to pick up all modules? Such as,

```
"module/Artcle/source/"
"module/Book/source/"
"module/Contact/source/"
"module/Admin/Article/source/"
"module/Admin/Book/source/"
"module/Admin/Contact/source/"
....
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot have wildcards in the directory path of an autoloading definition.

You can however adjust your project to allow having ANY class of a module being autoloaded by changing your directory structure. You have to get rid of all levels that are not mentioned in the fully qualified class name, i.e. no "source"

"Article/source/Article/Model/ArticleModel.php" hosting `\Foo\Article\Model\ArticleModel` would be required to live in "Article/Model/ArticleModel.php"

The always possible alternative is to mention all modules in the autoloading, or to split them into Composer packages on their own.

Remark regarding performance: Always try to use the longest prefix possible for autoloading. `"psr-0": { "" : "library" }` will force Composer to look into that library directory and search for a matching file FOR ALL CLASSES you load. Although Composer tries to optimize this by remembering failures, it still has an impact.

You should always add the prefixes that uniquely identify the location of a class, and you can add more than one prefix pointing to the same location for PSR-0. With PSR-4, the location differs by nature.

Think about writing a script that generates your autoloading definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope that Composer will have wildcard expansion in the autoload definition soon as it doesn't make sense while you can do that in `"require"`, such as `"slim/views": "0.1.*"` but not in `"autoload"`.

Comment: Create an issue on Github for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can require this composer plugin. It allows the usage of wildcards:

[psr4-advanced-wildcard-composer-plugin](https://github.com/teewurst/psr4-advanced-wildcard-composer-plugin)

Comment: "Could not find a matching version of package teewurst/psr4-advanced-wildcard-composer-plugin." - would you mind to add to packagist?

Comment: Done - https://packagist.org/packages/teewurst/psr4-advanced-wildcard-composer-plugin

Answer (score -1):

Here, should work

```
module\/.*?\/source\/
```

**Note** from your pattern `"module/*/source/"`, the `*` here will also work well on `bash` shell, It's called [globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) (pathname expansion).

**Additional information**

To done the path expansion in `JSON` you can use `JSONPath` which has an easy example here

**XPath vs JSONPath**

XPath: `/store/*`

JSONPath: `$.store.*`

Ref:http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: I think the answer maybe can not because json is a purely data object. Possible way maybe process it later using php.

Comment: Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Unsupported_native_data_types tells you that JSON doesn't support regex data type which might imply that pathname expansion in JSON is impossible.

Comment: @teelou I found it you can use `JsonPath` which allow you to use path expansion.

Comment: Are you discussing the possibilities of a generic JSON being able to allow wildcard expansion? This doesn't matter at all, because the JSON is going to be used by Composer - and Composer does not offer the feature to have wildcard expansion in the autoload definition. If you want to have it, send a pull request - until then: It won't work.